# How to replace the values on top of existing values using python

Tags: python-3.x, imputation

I have two dataset (`sample_set` and `third_set`), using `sample_set` I want to replace the values in third_set for only those values which equals `'Assessment' = 'Invalid Data'`

```
sample_data['Volume_new'] = third_set['Assessment'].replace(['Invalid Data'], mean_value)
```

above code has replaced the values in sample_set but remaining values are showing `null`.
[Data of Sample_set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoiIp.png)